# Wrap a input type of checkbox inside a div with a particular class

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
$('#createcase').on('pagebeforeshow', function(e) {  

    if ($('input', e.target).attr("type") === 'checkbox')
    {
        $('input[type=checkbox]',e.target).wrap("<div>");
        $('input[type=checkbox]',e.target).attr("class","ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on ui-first-child");         
    }
    else
    {
        $('input', e.target).filter('input:not(#mybutton)').wrap("<div class='ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear'>");
    }
});
```

My HTML contains:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" name=""/> Reminder
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="1"/> Reminder
<input type="checkbox" value="No" name="2"/>
```

My code is something like above however it never comes inside the if loop through i have checkboxes inside my html input

Comment: If possible, can  post `html` , remainder of `js` including `e.target` ? What is the requirement ? Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: Have added the snippets

Comment: i need to wrap the input types with checkbox in some other div with a different class

Comment: Can;t understand your question properly

Comment: @RashminJaviya I want to wrap a checkbox type input field inside a div with a class ui-checkbox. The problem is my html is being generated dynamically so having to apply styling from jquery

Comment: are you sure there is `pagebeforeshow` event in that `#createcase` HTML Node ??

Comment: I am using jquery mobile @MajedDH

Comment: sorry , didn't noticed .. and i don't know any thing about jquery mobile ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $("#createcase").on("pagebeforeshow", function(e) {
        var _class = "ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on ui-first-child";
        var div = $("<div />");
        var checks = $(e.target).find("input[type=checkbox]");
        var notchecks = $(e.target).find("input[type!=checkbox]");
        $(checks).addClass(_class).wrap(div);
        $(notchecks).wrap($(div).addClass(_class));
        console.log(checks, notchecks.parent(), notchecks);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/N29rd/

Answer (score -1):

i think it would work with some edits :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {  

    if ($('input', e.target).attr("type") === 'checkbox')
    {
        $('input[type=checkbox]',e.target).wrap("<div>");
        $('input[type=checkbox]',e.target).addClass("ui-btn ui-corner-all")
        .addClass("ui-btn-inherit")
        .addClass("ui-btn-icon-left")
        .addClass("ui-checkbox-on")
        .addClass("ui-first-child");         
    }
    else
    {
        $('input', e.target).filter('input:not(#mybutton)').wrap("<div class='ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear'>");
    }
});
```